# vi randomly echoing key presses

Tags: vim, vi

When using vi it sometimes echoes keypresses to the screen. For example, if I press escape, it will show ^[ on the screen. The actual characters don't get written to the file, because if I go to another place in the file and come back, the characters aren't there. Still, it's confusing when this happens, especially if the characters appear where there's text.

I also have gvim installed. It never happens there, but it happens in all the various types of vi that run in a terminal.

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you use Vi or Vim? Also, if you type `:version`, what is the output?

Comment: I'm using vim version 7.3.154.

Comment: Are you using Vim remotely over a telnet or ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay when you are working on slow connection. 
It also happened to me, when I used vim/vi on remote machine over **slow** connection.  It's because the slow connection extends the internal speed vim responds to your keystrokes.  For me, **nothing harmful** but it's slow, and gives exception to eyes.  At least VI is designed in this kind of condition, it can handle slow connection very well.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really help you fix the problem, but if it's just noise in the terminal, you could use the `:redr[aw]!` command to clean up your screen.